# convert byte array to double

Tags: java, type-conversion

Why am I getting garbage out of the following function?

The incoming `_data` argument is `byte[] = {6D, F3, B4, 15}`
The `_endian` argument is `ByteOrder.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN`

```
 ByteBuffer m_ByteBuffer; 
 public static double ByteToDouble(byte[] _data, int offset, ByteOrder _endian){
        synchronized (m_ByteBuffer) {
            m_ByteBuffer.clear();
            m_ByteBuffer.order(_endian);
            m_ByteBuffer.position(0);
            m_ByteBuffer.get(_data);
            m_ByteBuffer.position(0);
        }
        return m_ByteBuffer.getDouble();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please note that this is an English-speaking site, few here understand what looks like Korean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not written in english

Comment: There's no good reason to leave your commented lines in there to confuse and clutter the code. Your job to help us to help you is to make your question as focused and clear and clean and easy for us to figure out what the problem is as possible without having to guess whether you're leaving code in there to explain something to us or just because of laziness.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little example to see, how the converting could be done back and forth.

Hope it helps.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class ByteToDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double d1 = 123.456;
        double d2 = bytesToDouble(doubleToBytes(d1));

        System.out.printf("d1: %f\nd2: %f\n", d1, d2);
    }

    public static byte[] doubleToBytes(double d) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        dos.writeDouble(d);
        dos.flush();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static double bytesToDouble(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        return buffer.getDouble();
    }
}
```

Note that the `ByteBuffer#getDouble()` method will throw an `BufferUnderflowException`, if there are fewer than eight bytes remaining in the buffer. (see JavaDoc)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use

```
m_ByteBuffer.get(_data);
```

which would read the data of the buffer into `_data`. I suppose what you wanted to use was [ByteBuffer#put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put-byte:A-)

```
m_ByteBuffer.put(_data);
```

Additionally, after putting data into the buffer, it is more common to use [flip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#flip--) instead of `position(0)` since that correctly sets the limit of the buffer. All in all this would result roughly in:

```
m_ByteBuffer.order(_endian);

m_ByteBuffer.clear();
m_ByteBuffer.put(_data);
m_ByteBuffer.flip();
m_ByteBuffer.getDouble();
```

Comment: Thank you!!
I tried running flip ().
However, an error occurred and the program died.

Error : 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Comment: @RAYZIE to clarify: the BufferUnderflowException gets thrown on the call to getDouble (according to the docs, flip can not throw)? Keep in mind that `double` means 8 bytes. You might mean to use `getFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

4 bytes represent a `float`, 8 bytes a `double`.

```
byte[] data = {0x6D, 0xF3, 0xB4, 0x15};
double x = bytesToDouble(data);

public static double bytesToDouble(byte[] data) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return data.length == 4 ? bb.getFloat() : bb.getDouble();
}
```

`ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[])` is a light weight wrapping of the array, with writing capability to the bytes. A global ByteBuffer is not necessarily faster, certainly not when needing synchronisation.